# Can I push my data directly to Heroku without using PG Backup Add-on?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I have the database schema ready on my Heroku App, but I want to push my data directly from my local database to Heroku.

Heroku dev center says it can be done using PG Backup Addon and pg_dump.

Any other way of doing it?

Comment: did you have a look at the taps gem? `heroku db:push` https://github.com/ricardochimal/taps

Comment: What local db are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `heroku db:push`

```
$> heroku pg:push --help
Usage: heroku pg:push <LOCAL_SOURCE_DATABASE> <REMOTE_TARGET_DATABASE>

 Push from LOCAL_SOURCE_DATABASE to REMOTE_TARGET_DATABASE
 REMOTE_TARGET_DATABASE must be empty.
```

Comment: @Winfield-I have already run db:migrate on Heroku. Do I need to remove the database from it and then run the above command?

Comment: Do I need to replace LOCAL_SOURCE_DATABASE with the DB name?

Comment: LOCAL_SOURCE_DATABASE is the name of your local database.  REMOTE_TARGET_DATABASE is the URL to your primary database. When you run this, it will replace the contents of the remote db with your local DB.

Comment: @Winfield- I tried replacing LOCAL_SOURCE_DATABASE with postgres://username:password@host/database. But it says it is not a valid database name.

Comment: How do I get the Local Source Database?

Comment: Do you have a local database running?  This is the URL to that database.

Comment: I have done it using Heroku PGBackups Addon as given on Heroku Dev center